# simple-type-error

Tags: arrays, types, lisp, common-lisp

I've made an executable that includes calls to arrays. When I execute the program, I get the error

```
Condition of type: SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR
In function AREF, the index into the object
 #(0.00387149 3.0345068e-4 5.9720734e-4 -1.6648759e-5 0.058811672).
takes a value 5 out of the range (INTEGER 0 4).
```

I looked up  simple-type-error, and I believe it occurs when a value is of an unexpected type. However I was of the impression that you don't have to specify types in Lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to, but a Lisp system hopefully will complain when you call a function with the wrong type of object.

```
CL-USER 7 > (sin "a string")

Error: In SIN of ("a string") arguments should be of type NUMBER.
```

The LispWorks error report for your problem is bit less 'technical':

```
CL-USER 8 > (aref #(a b c d) 4)

Error: The subscript 4 exceeds the limit 3 for the first dimension 
of the array #(A B C D).
```

Which makes sense, since dimensions are zero-based. The above vector has index 0, 1, 2, and 3. But not 4.

```
CL-USER 10 > (typep 4 '(integer 0 3))
NIL
```

So 4 is not an integer in a range of 0 to 3.

Comment: Thanks very much, so that was what it meant. I'm in the process of narrowing down the bug- I loaded the lisp file in Clisp, and then reproduced the error- but it won't give me the line number the error is on- are you aware of a method for doing so?

Comment: @bracket: Since Lisp is not line-based, this is not generally possible. Some Lisp systems can associate errors with the responsible source code in files - but I don't think the CLISP implementation can do that can do that. In CLISP you look at the backtrace and you get the responsible function.